# FFmpeg; two channels lose sync while in transit?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, audio-streaming

I'm encountering a problem when using FFmpeg to stream a stereo soundtrack (audio-only) from (internet-)location A to B.
The problem is the left- and right-channel time-shift in relation to one another, this time-shift measuring some 12 msec.

I did measure this with the following set-up:

**Transmission-end:** Audacity/metronome function generating pulses (1/sec), feeding the output of Audacity to both FFmpeg (jack-) input-channels in parallel, using the following FFmpeg command-script:

```
ffmpeg  -hide_banner \
        -loglevel verbose \
        -f jack -channels 1 -thread_queue_size 1024 -i Tonmeister_mic1 \
        -f jack -channels 1 -thread_queue_size 1024 -i Tonmeister_mic2 \
        -map 0 \
        -map 1 \
        -codec:a libopus \
        -b:a 128k \
        -vbr on \
        -packet_loss 10 \
        -fec on \
        -compression_level 10 \
        -frame_duration 20 \
        -application audio \
        -f mpegts \
        udp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:4524
```

**Receiver-end:** write the incoming stream directly to disk using the following command:

ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel verbose -thread_queue_size 64 -i udp://127.0.0.1:4524 -map 0 -filter_complex "[0:a:0][0:a:1]amerge=inputs=2" metronome_at_Uli.wav

and subsequently load that file in Audacity to visualize the two (incoming) channels.

[image: Incoming signals have time-shifted???]

The picture clearly shows the 12msec time-shift that apparently was introduced between the two channels while in (FFmpeg-)transit.

What am I doing wrong? What can be done to overcome this issue?

Note:
Tranmission-end runs Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS, FFmpeg version 4.2.7-0ubuntu0.1 . Receiving-end: MacOS Big Sur, 11.7.1, FFmpeg version 5.1.2

Note: it's my intention to use this technique to transmit 10 - 15 mono-channels over one stream/udp-channel.

Comment: Ideally, to begin with, your input format should supply accurate source timestamps with reference to the same clock. If so, then ffmpeg 6.0+ has option `-isync` to maintain sync. If not, then are only mitigations to attempt sync, such as reducing probing parameters.

Comment: Can you not make these 2 mono sources into a single stereo before you start to stream it? [idk a thing about ffmpeg, but I do know a stereo file won't slip out of sync ;)